# I am unable to install Turi Create on Mac M1

Tags: python-3.x, macos, data-science, apple-m1, turi-create

**Please help me out**

I am unable to install Turicreate
I have referred to the website https://github.com/apple/turicreate

I have Python 3.8.0 installed currently which suits the system requirements.

I have followed the steps:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

then

```
# Create a Python virtual environment
cd ~
virtualenv venv

# Activate your virtual environment
source ~/venv/bin/activate
```

and finally

```
(venv) pip install -U turicreate
```

and i'm getting the error message like this:

```
              ==================================================================================
          TURICREATE ERROR
  
          If you see this message, pip install did not find an available binary package
          for your system.
  
          Supported Platforms:
              * macOS 10.12+ x86_64.
              * Linux x86_64 (including WSL on Windows 10).
  
          Support Python Versions:
              * 2.7
              * 3.5
              * 3.6
              * 3.7
              * 3.8
  
          Another possible cause of this error is an outdated pip version. Try:
              `pip install -U pip`
  
          ==================================================================================
  
  
  
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for turicreate
Running setup.py clean for turicreate
Failed to build turicreate
Installing collected packages: turicreate
Running setup.py install for turicreate ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Running setup.py install for turicreate did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [30 lines of output]
running install
/Users/samyuktag/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
warnings.warn(

```
          ==================================================================================
          TURICREATE ERROR
  
          If you see this message, pip install did not find an available binary package
          for your system.
  
          Supported Platforms:
              * macOS 10.12+ x86_64.
              * Linux x86_64 (including WSL on Windows 10).
  
          Support Python Versions:
              * 2.7
              * 3.5
              * 3.6
              * 3.7
              * 3.8
  
          Another possible cause of this error is an outdated pip version. Try:
              `pip install -U pip`
  
          ==================================================================================
  
  
  
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> turicreate

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Users/samyuktag/venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
(virtual_environment_name) (venv) samyuktag@Samyuktas-MacBook-Air ~ %

**Please help me out**

Comment: See this![pip install -U turicreate Showing Error (using python3 and windows 10](https://github.com/apple/turicreate/issues/3149)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you are installing it on a M1;
Please see the following comment

[Unable to install on M1 Mac with Python 3.8.12](https://github.com/apple/turicreate/issues/3442#issuecomment-1058281045)

[image]